# How to combine two different Parameter arrays into a single array using Loadrunner?

Tags: parameters, loadrunner

I am using Loadrunner Vugen script. In my script we use **web_reg_save_param** for saving into the array.
For instance;

```
web_reg_save_param("timeslot","LB={\"dateTime\":\"","RB=\",\"status\"", "ORD=ALL",LAST);
web_reg_save_param("timeslot1","LB={\"dateTime\":\"","RB=\",\"status\"", "ORD=ALL",LAST);
```

We will get different timeslots in each request. I need to combine these two arrays into a single array with all the values.

Any Pointers will help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what your code should look (roughly) like, assuming it will go into a LoadRunner array called alltimeslots.  Code is directly from head to keyboard without execution in LoadRunner, so take any small defects as par for the course for this type of on the paper draft.

```
int  index,
     timeslot_limit,
     timeslot1_limit;
char arrayname[20]="",
     sourcename[20]="";

    ...

timeslot_limit=atoi( lr_eval_string("{timeslot_count}") );
timeslot1_limit=atoi( lr_eval_string("{timeslot1_count}") );
//conversion once to avoid the constant hit on atoi() conversion inside of loop

for ( index=1, index<=timeslot_limit, index++ )
{
   sprintf( arrayname, "alltimeslots_%d", index );
   sprintf( sourcename, "{timeslot_%d}", index );
   lr_save_string( lr_eval_string(sourcename), arrayname );
}

for ( index=1, index<=timeslot1_limit, index++ )
{
   sprintf( arrayname, "alltimeslots_%d", ( index+timeslot_limit ) );
   sprintf( sourcename, "{timeslot1_%d}", index );
   lr_save_string( lr_eval_string(sourcename), arrayname );
}

lr_save_int( ( timeslot_limit+timeslot1_limit ), "alltimeslots_count" );
```

Programming skills are a foundation class of skills for performance testing